# Liferay 7 How to publish single page from staging site to live site using page layout id?

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

I am developing **custom portlet** to publish single page from staging site to live site in liferay 7. I want to publish 
page using page layout id (plid).

Main requirment is when I publish page then all data means (web content , custom portlet or OOB portlet) which are on this page also need to publish with page publish.

I Have already Try using below methods :

1) public long publishToLive(PortletRequest portletRequest) method of StagingImpl class.

2) public MissingReferences publishStagingRequest(
            long userId, long stagingRequestId,
            ExportImportConfiguration exportImportConfiguration) fo StaginLocalServiceImpl class

3) public long publishLayouts(
            long userId, long sourceGroupId, long targetGroupId,
            boolean privateLayout, long[] layoutIds,
            Map parameterMap) method of StagingImpl class

But in all above method page publish successfully but not publish web content of that particular page.

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve above requirement using custom portlet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more details on what you've done so far. Stock reasons to close questions on stackoverflow include "asking for tutorial" and "too broad". The way you phrase your question would match both criteria. Also: You state Liferay 7, but tag Liferay 6 and Liferay 7. Please decide, edit your question with the information and tag appropriately.

Comment: I Have already Try using below methods :
1) public long publishToLive(PortletRequest portletRequest) method of StagingImpl class.
2) public MissingReferences publishStagingRequest(
   long userId, long stagingRequestId,
   ExportImportConfiguration exportImportConfiguration)
3) public long publishLayouts(
   long userId, long sourceGroupId, long targetGroupId,
   boolean privateLayout, long[] layoutIds,
   Map<String, String[]> parameterMap)

But in all above method page publish successfully but not publish web content of that perticular page.

Comment: are you trying to stage a layout programmatically within a custom portlet ?

Comment: Yes Andre, 
But in this case my portlet which is on the page is publish properly but web content is not publish

Comment: @RobertJack , have to confess that I never did that programmatically , but seems like , that the layout settings and the portlets on a layout get done .. web content has separate content types .. the journal articles ...you should find a way to do  that ..

Comment: @RobertJack ,, for example  this might be a starting point  https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/7-1/staging-content-for-publication,, by the way .. address people directly using @<name>  this way we get a mail ,,